# React-native app build problem after install react-native-vector-icons

Tags: android, windows, react-native, android-icons

I have a problem in a react-native project after install react-native-vector-icons and try to build android app in the emulator. I'm working on Windows.
I installed the library and linked it as said in the manual, but I think I have a dependency problem.

```
C:\react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\user\Source\reactnative\myapp\node_modules (43ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\Source\reactnative\myapp\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android\build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
```

Installed versions:
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",

Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/473#issuecomment-351396188

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to either downgrade the `vector-icons` version or upgrade `react-native + react` versions.

Another option is to manually update your `gradle` and `gradle-wrapper` versions in the android project.

So update the gradle version in the top-level gradle file:

Usually located here: `project_name/android/build.gradle`

Change to:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

And also the gradle-wrapper:

Usually located here: `project_name/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Change to:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After several problems with the version of the gradle and react-native on Win10, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same errors, the following steps worked for me:

1.change the code in android/build/gradle.

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

In the above code, google() is added in buildscript and allprojects and
classpath gradle version is replaced by the gradle version of classpath in **..\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android\build.gradle** (mine is 3.3.1, yours can be different).

2. in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, modify the distributionUrl:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
   ```

Version of the above library is 4.10.1, The minimum version of the above library required by gradle version 3.3.1 is 4.10.1, so I installed gradle-4.10.1-all.zip in my project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall vector-icons (remove wire-react-vector-icons-native)
2. Delete the folder node_modules
3. Then `yarn install`
4. Type this command `yarn add react-native-vector-icons`
5. Then this `react-link native command react-native-vector-icons`
6. Then this command `reage-nactive run- android 7 then react-native start --reset-cache`

These steps worked for me